# App on Facebook

Tags: php, facebook, canvas, sdk

I'm trying to run the example.php file that comes with the facebook sdk. I do have a hosting server that runs php, and also changed the ID's to the corresponding one on my app. Here is the message i'm getting:

```
This webpage is not available
The webpage at https://filipeximenes.com/facebook/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error.
```

i'm pointing the canvas to this adress: http://filipeximenes.com/facebook/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I think that this is your problem:

Do you have a valid security certificate on the hosting server?  I ran into that problem recently when deploying an FB app.  Since October, you have to have a valid cert even in sandbox mode for the FB app to run properly.  If you don't have one it causes weird problems.

Just a thought that I hope helps.

One other thing to do from a debugging perspective is to take a look at the actual app running on your hosting server without viewing it via FB.  If you get the same error message there, you know that it has nothing to do with the FB SDK.

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The app is running smooth outside facebook (http://filipeximenes.com/facebook/).
I'm new on web developing, so I don't know if i have a valid security certificate on my server. How fo i check it? And if i don't have one, how do i get it?

Comment: Ok, since it is running smoothly outside of FB, I am now certain that this is a certificate issue.  Now about getting a certificate: you should check with your web host for the cheapest option IMO.  Do you expect lot's of traffic?  If not, then many smaller web hosting accounts offer a https/certificates for a small additional fee.  Just do a google search for "SSL Certificates".  Most hosting companies also provide detailed guides for creating and incorporating the certificate into your site.